# How to apply default themes in PowerPoint using power-shell

Tags: vba, powershell, themes, powerpoint, default

I've been asked at work to make sure everyone has the same default theme on their PowerPoint application so that everyone is uniform and compliant. Problem is i dont know how but i know Power-Shell can do that for me. I've started on a good tip but this script did not work for me.

```
Add-type -AssemblyName office
$Application = New-Object -ComObject powerpoint.application
$application.visible = [Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState]::msoTrue

$themePath = "C:\Users\emp\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\Document Themes\Theme1.thmx"
$path = "C:\Users\emp\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\Document Themes"
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Include "*.ppt", "*.pptx" -Recurse |
ForEach-Object {
 $presentation = $application.Presentations.open($_.fullname)
 $presentation.ApplyTemplate($themePath)
 $presentation.Save()
 $presentation.Close()
 "Modifying $_.FullName"
} 

$application.quit()
$application = $null
[gc]::collect()
[gc]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

Can anyone shed any light on how to change the default theme using powershell? Any help would be greatly appreciated!